# Excel VBA: output the result of a WinHTTPRequest in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

How do I output the result of a `WinHTTPRequest` in Excel?

For example, the following code queries the stock quote of Apple from a webpage but it doesn't output anything:

```
Sub GetQuotes()

     Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, pontod As Object

     On Error Resume Next
     Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
     With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
         .Open "GET", "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=AAPL.O", False
         .send
         oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
     End With

     'Price
     Set pontod = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("sectionQuote nasdaqChange")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(1)
     MsgBox pontod.innerText

End Sub
```

While this runs perfectly for the name:

```
Sub GetQuotes2()

     Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, pontod As Object

     On Error Resume Next
     Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
     With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
         .Open "GET", "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=AAPL.O", False
         .send
         oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
     End With

     'Name
     Set pontod = oHtml.getElementById("sectionTitle").getElementsByTagName("h1")(0)
     MsgBox pontod.innerText

End Sub
```

I'd like to be able to fetch the whole page and look for specific HTML elements in it, but how do I manage to see the whole response from the query?

Comment: see [getElementsByClassName, HTMLSource's double quotation marks are gone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302502/vba-getelementsbyclassname-htmlsources-double-quotation-marks-are-gone/34304544#34304544).

Comment: @Jeeped thanks, I got that .getElementById is working while .getElementsByClassName is not. but I'm still not there (I've read the post you indicate)

Comment: fwiw, when developing xmlHTTP requests, I use fiddler in a browser navigated to the same page that I am sending the request to. If you still need to see the whole page, a Ctrl+U in just about any browser will show the background HTML. Possible open a quick file object or ado.stream and write .responseText to a TXT or HTML.

Comment: In your first example, try replacing the declaration `html As Object` with `ohtml As HTMLDocument` and remove the "On Error Resume Next" line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeeped said above, the method `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work on an XML request.

However, by looking at the webpage you're trying to scrape, you can work-around the issue by using this line:

```
Set pontod = oHtml.getElementById("headerQuoteContainer").getElementsByTagName("span")(1)
```

instead of this one:

```
Set pontod = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("sectionQuote nasdaqChange")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(1)
```

As you can observe from the HTML structure of the webpage:

[image]

... your price is not only the second `span` element of the first `div` with class names `sectionQuote` and `nasdaqChange`, but also the second `span` element of the unique object with id `headerQuoteContainer`.

Hence, scrape it from there will avoid you to use the invalid method `getElementsByClassName` (which is a valid HTML method, but not when the HTML is an XML response) for the classic `getElementById()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's correct. It doesn't work with getElementsByClassName.
It does work if instead of winhttprequest a browser an object browser is created to navigate to the desired page.