# Object does not support property or method getElementsByClassName IE object

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get the above error when I try and select element by classname in vba.

```
 Dim ie As Object
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
 Dim url As String
 url="https://sdsds.com"
 ie.Visible = True
 ie.navigate url

 Set objTables = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
 Set datatables = objTables(8)
 Set wb = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("wb")(0)
```

Strange thing is that `getElementsByTagName("table")` works fine. But `getElementsByClassName` throws this error. I am not sure why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vba, getElementsByClassName, HTMLSource's double quotation marks are gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302502/vba-getelementsbyclassname-htmlsources-double-quotation-marks-are-gone)

Comment: How did you define `wb`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of IE, you may not have that method available to you.

There is a site that I like to use to see what is and is not available in different browsers:
https://caniuse.com/#search=Getelementsbyclassname

Comment: My IE Version is 11.175.183. Which supporst getElementByClassName